# Docker SSH login fails remotely

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, ssh, dockerfile

I've created a docker within AWS server which runs SSH service.
I relied on the following example: https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/ and added my own logic to the Dockerfile.

When trying to log in remotely to the docker I get the password message prompted but the password I set for the SSH user does not work. When trying the exact same password with local ssh connection (from within the AWS server to 127.0.0.1 -p exported_SSH_port) it works perfectly.

any ideas?

Comment: Need more details. Show the logs when you do `ssh -vv -p <port> <user>@host`. Also how you ran the container? Add output of `docker ps` to your question

Comment: which user do you specify while trying to connect to your container in both cases?

Answer (score 0):

There's a little bug in docker docs:
[image: Dockerize an SSH service]

You should change

```
RUN sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

To

```
RUN sed -i 's/#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```